How do I add a shadow all the way around a CircleShape
I'm trying to re-create this button I made in SwiftUi in Jetpack Compose, but I can't seem to apply a shadow all the way round the circle.  The shadow only seems to appear around the bottom half of the circle.  How can I fix this?


Button(
    onClick = {},
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(60.dp)
        .border(
            width = 1.dp,
            color = Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.5F),
            shape = CircleShape
        )
        .shadow(
            elevation = 15.dp,
            shape = CircleShape,
            ambientColor = Color.Green,
            spotColor = Color.Green,
        ),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
        containerColor = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
            Color.Black
        } else {
            Color.White
        }
    )
) {
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Rounded.ThumbUp,
        contentDescription = "null",
        tint = Color.Green,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(35.dp)

    )
}


Elevation of the object ideally gives the shadow and that is how it works. If you need shadow effect on entire circle, you need to use Box and create a circle gradient shadow at the bottom and place the widget on top.

okay, so your code works, not sure if parent layouts are interfering with it.
Ive used it in my project , and looks good with shadow


Thanks for checking.  Bizarrely, I copied the same code into a new project and I'm still getting what I shared in my question.  Even in dark mode as you've shared, I get a similar shadow only around the bottom of the circle.

which device are you using?

Pixel 8 Pro Emulator running VanillaIceCream.  Using Android Studio Jellyfish 2023.3.1.  compose_ui_version = '1.3.3'

Maybe you can use the Box composable along with Modifier functions to achieve this effect.
@Composable
fun ShadowedCircle(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shadowColor: Color = Color.Green,
    shadowElevation: Dp = 15.dp,
    circleColor: Color = Color.Green,
    size: Dp = 60.dp
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(size)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(circleColor)
            .shadow(elevation = shadowElevation, shape = CircleShape, ambientColor = shadowColor)
    ) {
        Icon()
    }
}

